# the distance between 2 points on a curve C=xy

Tags: integration, arc-length

So I am no mathematician and have a curve the equation of which is $y=c/x$, or $c= xy$ where $c$ is a constant. I want to calculate the length of the curve between two points but my maths is not sufficient to be able to get beyond the equation for the integral.

I have
$$\int \sqrt{1+ (c/x)^2} dx$$
but stuck at that point.

Anyone fancy helping out?

Comment: Your integral is wrong, you forgot to differentiate.

Comment: as I said useless at maths- if you could help me get from the starting equation to the answer 'formula' that would be great

Comment: The correct integral is $\int \sqrt{1+\frac{c^2}{x^4}} \, dx$, it's non-elementary, you may calculate it as $-\frac{c}{x}\;_2F_1(-\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{4};\tfrac{3}{4};-\tfrac{x^4}{c^2})$

Comment: many thanks :-)